# How to intercept EJB's when loaded

Tags: spring, jakarta-ee, ejb, cdi

I have a few EJBs (annotated with @Stateless) which are loaded when I call them (i.e. they are not
eagerly loaded when my application server boots).

Some of them contain a custom method annotation, lets call it @Foo.

I want to find a way to scan all of them when my application server (AS)
boots and find which ones are annotated with @Foo.

So far I have registered in web.xml a lifecycle listener which is called
on AS boot.

- PS#1: @PostConstruct is called when my EJBs are first called which
  may be on a later time after my AP boots.
- PS#2: Is there an event thrown when my EJBs are registered on JNDI?
- PS#3: I thing Spring does something similar when you configure it to scan all classes
  under a package

Comment: Is @Foo a CDI quailifer?

Answer (score 0):

If the EJB is constructed by Spring, then you can use a Spring bean post processor (this is what Spring uses when it performs it's scan).

```
@Component
public class FooFinder implements BeanPostProcessor {

    List<Method> fooMethods = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    public Object postProcessBeforeInitialization(Object bean, String beanName) throws BeansException {
        Class<?> targetClass = AopUtils.getTargetClass(bean);
        for (Method method : targetClass.getDeclaredMethods()){
            for (Annotation annotation : AnnotationUtils.getAnnotations(method)){
                if (annotation instanceof Foo){
                    fooMethods.add(method);
                }
            }
        }
        return bean;
    }

    @Override
    public Object postProcessAfterInitialization(Object bean, String beanName) throws BeansException {
        return bean;
    }
}
```

Also be warned... be careful about dependency injection into your BeanPostProcessor.  You may create problems with the Spring dependency graph, as the BeanPostProcessors must be created first.  If you need to register the method with some other bean, make the BeanPostProcessor ApplicationContextAware or BeanFactoryAware, and get the bean that way.